# Inner product on the space of sections

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, fiber-bundles

Let $L\to M$ be a real line bundle over a manifold $M$, and let us denote by $\Gamma(L)$ its space of sections. I am trying to find a product in $\Gamma(L)$ to make it into an algebra. The naive product defined on every local trivialization $(U,\phi)$ as

$(s_{1}\cdot s_{2})|_{U}(p) =(p, \phi(s_{1}(p))\phi(s_{2}(p)))\, , \qquad p\in M\, ,$

gives as a result a section of the square line bundle, $s_{1}\cdot s_{2}\in \Gamma(L^{2})$, so it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: An inner product doesn't make something an algebra. You mean so you can take the Clifford algebra? You can always pick a Riemannian metric by picking it locally and using a partition of unity to get it globally, but this is an extra choice you make.

Comment: Indeed an inner product does not make something into an algebra, but I was assuming that the set of sections $\Gamma(L)$ is already a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. This fact together with an inner product makes $\Gamma(L)$ into an algebra. What I have in mind is to obtain something like the algebra of functions on any manifold $M$, which is the algebra of sections of the trivial line bundle $\Gamma(M\times\mathbb{R})$ (I know that the set of functions on a manifold is also a ring, but in particular is an algebra).

Comment: I don't see it. What's the multiplication? (The trivial line bundle is special because it can be equipped with the structure of a monoid object in the category of vector bundles; that is, it's equipped with a map $L \otimes L \to L$ satisfying associativity and so forth.)

Comment: That is the point: I want to know if there is a "multiplication" that makes the vector space of sections $\Gamma(L)$ of the line bundle into an algebra. In other words, I want to know if the special situation happening for trivial line bundles can be generalized to non-trivial line bundles (although I don't need the inner product to be associative or satisfy any particular conditions). In any case, there is a natural map $\Gamma(L)\otimes\Gamma(L)\to \Gamma(L^2)$, but of course that is not inner.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but what do you think an inner product has to do with it? You want a map $L \otimes L \to L$, not a map $L \otimes L \to \mathbb{R}$. And I believe $L$ has a monoid structure iff it's trivializable; the unit map $1 \to L$ has to be everywhere nonzero so it's a trivialization.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: when I wrote "inner product", I was meaning a map from $L\times L$ to itself, not $\mathbb{R}$. I see that that was not a correct terminology. In any case, it is not necessary to require $\Gamma(L)$ to be a monoid (otherwise, as you explain $L$ would be trivial). In particular, the original question was about an algebra structure on $\Gamma(L)$, without any further requirements (such as associativity or existence of a unit).

Comment: That's easy, then: take the zero map.

Comment: I was after a non-trivial map, but thanks ;).

Comment: Well, there isn't such a map which is everywhere nonzero (because then $L \otimes L \to L$ is an isomorphism, and that implies that $L$ is trivializable again).

Comment: I wasn't expecting the map to be everywhere non-zero. Suppose that $s_{1}\in\Gamma(L)$ as $n_{1}$ zeros and $s_{2}\in\Gamma(L)$ as $n_{2}$ zeros. Then I was expecting the number of zeroes of $s_{1}\cdot s_{2}\in\Gamma(L)$ to be less or equal than $n_{1}+n_{2}$.

Comment: That's not what I mean by "everywhere nonzero." I mean that the induced map $L_x \otimes L_x \to L_x$ is nonzero for every $x$ (this is satisfied by the usual multiplication on $\mathbb{R}$, for example).

Comment: Then I don't see the problem: the point is that every section in $\Gamma(L)$ has at least one zero, so even using a map which is everywhere non-zero the result of multiplying two sections will be a section with zeros. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: The point is that such a map induces an isomorphism of line bundles $L \otimes L \cong L$, and after multiplying by $L^{-1}$ on both sides we get that $L$ is trivializable.

Comment: Mmmm I am not sure if I understand it. Let us assume that $L$ is non-trivial and that $\cdot\colon\Gamma(L)\times\Gamma(L)\to\Gamma(L)$ is a map. How would you construct from $\cdot$ a nowhere vanishing section on $L$? (just to see from a different point of view that $L$ would be trivializable) What I don't see is how using $\cdot$, which maps pairs of sections to section, one can show that $L\times L\simeq L$.

Answer (score 0):

> **Claim:** Let $L$ be a real line bundle over a space $X$. Suppose $m : L \otimes L \to L$ is a map of line bundles which is everywhere nonzero in the sense that the maps $m_x : L_x \otimes L_x \to L_x$ are nonzero for every $x \in X$. Then $L$ is trivializable.

*Proof.* A map between line bundles which is everywhere nonzero is everywhere an isomorphism, and hence an isomorphism, so $L \otimes L \cong L$. Tensoring by the inverse line bundle $L^{-1} \cong L^{\ast}$, it follows that

$$L \cong L^{-1} \otimes L \otimes L \cong L^{-1} \otimes L \cong 1.$$

Very explicitly, at each point $x \in X$, choose a nonzero vector $v_x \in L_x$. Then $m_x$ acts by

$$m_x : L_x \otimes L_x \ni v_x \otimes v_x \mapsto c_x v_x \in L_x.$$

for some constant $c_x$, depending both on $x$ and on the choice of vector $v_x$. By hypothesis, $m_x$ is nonzero, hence $c_x$ is nonzero, so we can write down the inverse map

$$m_x^{-1} : L_x \ni v_x \mapsto c_x^{-1} v_x \otimes v_x \in L_x \otimes L_x.$$

The corresponding nonzero section of $L$ is, at each point, the map in $L_x^{\ast} \otimes L_x \otimes L_x$ corresponding to $m_x^{-1}$, so explicitly it has value $c_x^{-1} v_x$ at each point $x$, and you can check for yourself that this doesn't depend on any choices.

Comment: Thanks for the explicit answer. Some comments:

- The inner product I am after maps pairs of sections to sections, namely $\cdot\colon \Gamma(L)\times \Gamma(L)\to\Gamma(L)$. In particular, it may not restrict to a well defined map on each fibre $m_{p}: L_{p}\times L_{p}\to L_{p}, p\in M$. For example, it may not be single-valued if there are several different sections passing through the same point in $L_{p}$.

- The product that I am after does not need to satisfy the "everywhere nonzero condition" that you impose.

Comment: @S.S.: then what are you after? If you don't ask for a bundle map then $\Gamma(L)$ is just some infinite-dimensional vector space and you can do whatever you want to it.

Comment: Well, as I stated in the original question, I am after a map $\cdot\colon \Gamma(L)\times \Gamma(L)\to \Gamma(L)$ making $\Gamma(L)$ into an algebra, which would be infinite-dimensional, as you pointed out. For example

$s_{1}\cdot s_{2} = \sqrt{|s_{1} s_{2}|}$

looks like a possibility, since it does not produce a nowhere vanishing section.

Comment: @S.S.: that won't distribute over addition. What kind of algebra structure do you want? If there are no requirements you can just pick one arbitrarily, although I don't know why you'd want to.

Comment: Well, I was just wondering about the existence of a map $\cdot\colon \Gamma(L)\times\Gamma(L)\to \Gamma(L)$ making $\Gamma(L)$ into an algebra and not trivializing $L$. If $s_{1}\cdot s_{2} = \sqrt{|s_{1}s_{2}|}$ does the job then that is fine, although it would be nice to have a product which is associative and distributive.

Comment: @Bilateral: again, $\Gamma(L)$ is just some infinite-dimensional vector space, so you can just *pick one* if there aren't any other requirements you want it to satisfy (although I don't know what the point of that would be). If you don't want it to be a bundle map then what is the point of discussing the line bundle $L$ in the first place?